# Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Receiving  Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Could someone help me debug and find why I receive this error with the .Find method?

```
Sub TestCode()
'===============================================================================================
'Description: Loops through the selected site and adds in the vulnerability totals for each _
    systems
'Originally written by: Troy Pilewski
'Date: 2016-06-30
'===============================================================================================

'Declares variables
Dim ToWorkbook, FromWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ToWorksheet, FromWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim DataRange, WholeRange As Range
Dim FromWorkbookVarient As Variant
Dim TitleString, FilterName, CurrentSystemName As String
Dim LastRow As Long

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set ToWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ToWorksheet = ToWorkbook.Worksheets("SITE")

LastRow = ToWorksheet.Range("Z:Z").Find( _
    What:="*", _
    After:=ToWorkbook.Range("Z1"), _
    LookAt:=xlByRows, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
).Row

MsgBox _
    Title:="Ship Range", _
    Prompt:="Z1:Z" & LastRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the error: `ToWorkbook.Range("Z1")`. can't set range to a workbook.

Fyi...
Also `Dim x , y as String` makes y as `string` and x as `variant`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will accept once the time limit permits. I must have missed that line. Although, not sure why you are say to declare the variables as you stated.

Comment: No additional answers before you upvote & accept the answer. Just kidding:) I said so , because for this line `Dim ToWorkbook, FromWorkbook As Workbook` only `FromWorkbook` is declared as type `Workbook`. `ToWorkbook` remains as `Variant`. Proper way is : `Dim ToWorkbook As Workbook, FromWorkbook As Workbook`

Comment: Roger! I understand!